# Just execute rest of code after complete a execution function in node?

Tags: javascript, node.js, while-loop

I´m trying to read a spreadsheet using node js and save data in database, but i have a problem with sync of the code.  The problem is that, the method getDataProduct runs 2230 times before insertProduct starts. When i look in dabatase just save  data from the last row. Anyone can help me?

```
try {
        excel_products.forEach(function (v, i) {
            x = 1;
            var run = true;

            while (run) {

                if (v.data[x] !== undefined) {
                    if (v.data[x][15] != '') {
                        getDataProduct(v, x);
                        insertProduct();
                        insertProductSku();
                        insertProductStore();
                    }
                } else {
                    run = false;
                }

               x++;
            }

        });
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
```

Update

I think that the problem is this function, inside insertProduct():

```
    sql_product = 'INSERT QUERY';
    connection.then(function () {

    new db.Request().query(sql_product).then(function (recordset) {
    }).catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error);
    });
    }).catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error);
    });
```

When i print the sql_product, its ok, but i think that function to save in database is too slow to run.

Comment: You should show insertProduct code, probably async call that you need wait for.

Comment: We need to see `getDataProduct()` and `insertProduct()` code as they are probably async and you need to code for them being async, not assume they are synchronous which it looks like you are doing.

Comment: I add the code inside the insertProduct();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a few thing that maybe can help:

1/ it is weird that the function insertProduct and the others use a global variable... I recommend to you use params.

2/ The promise from `db.Request().query` should be returned outside, maybe the return inside the promise should be true instead the response from database (don;t share info outside the function that it is not needed)

```
function insertProduct(product){
   sql_product = 'INSERT QUERY';

   .... 

   return db.Request().query(sql_product).then(function (recordset) {
      return true;
   }).catch(function (error) {
       console.log(error);
   })
}
```

if all your function does this you can do something like:

```
//We can jump de catch you have it inside the functions
insertProduct(product).then(function(){
      insertProductSku(product).then(function(){
            insertProductStore(product)
      })
})
```

\3 Look like you need the iteration in specific order you create a function like this adding the actual logic:

```
function nextIteration(pos) {
    var product = excel_products[pos];
    if (product.data[x] !== undefined) {
        if (product.data[x][15] != '') {
            var product = getDataProduct(v, x);
            insertProduct(product).then(function() {
                insertProductSku(product).then(function() {
                    insertProductStore(product).then(function() {
                        nextIteration(pos + 1)
                    });

                })
            })
        } else {
            nextIteration(pos + 1)
        }
    }
}

nextIteration(0);
```

This implementation is weird, I know, but you will resolve the next action when you already have the info. You can look around `promise.all()` if you don't care about the order or simplify the syntaxis with `.bind` but it is better to go step by step.

I didn't try to touch the logic too much. I hope I was clear enough.

Comment: Nice! Happy to help!

Answer (score 0):

You might want to consider using asyncjs for this: https://github.com/caolan/async

The eachSeries would call the insertProduct one at a time so long as you can equip the insertProduct() to call a callback when it finished it's task.

If you want to run more than one insert at a time, there is functions like the queue that could spawn x number of insertion tasks at a time.